# Can I run Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: laptop

Alright, since Windows 10 is just FULL of spyware and I don't want to use it, can I run Ubuntu 17.10?
Specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
  CPU: Intel Pentium J3710 1.60 GHz (bios says its N3710 I don't know who to trust)
- RAM:4GB DDR3 1599Mhz (11-11-11-28)
- Motherboard: Acer Stego_BA (CHV)
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 920mx 2GB, and well, Intel HD
- Hard Drive:931GB TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 (SATA)

Comment: Maybe.  The easiest way to tell would be to mount up a liveUSB and try to use Ubuntu.

Comment: Definitely you can run Ubuntu with that hardware and it will function. Your CPU architecture is supported by Linux. Whether or not it will be smooth and fast, that's something you can only find out in practice.

Answer (score -1):

check Ubuntu Installation/SystemRequirements here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements